# How to alter the values in a javascript file in rails using ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I suppose this is more of a principles or approach question but I just can't get my head around it. I have a graph and on it are nodes. I would like the size of the node to change depending on a value in a database. I've been told ajax is the way forward but Im not sure how to accomplish this so that the output of the ajax is then available for the separate javascript file that delivers the graph.
The way I see this is

a.Make the ajax call to the controller which returns the database value as json
b. Let's say the variable on success is called star
c. This star variable is then sent to the other javascript file lets say bill.js
d. The variable can then interact in bill.js

The problem I have is in understanding how the output of the ajax can then be available for another javascript file. Do I have to put the ajax output variable in a div and then call that div from the other javascript file. If so how?

Comment: Why does the data you get from your ajax call have to interact with another JS file? Usually you'd just execute the ajax call within the page you want to consume the resulting data. It sounds like you know how it works, just make an ajax call to your rails route from the page with the graphs, then instantiate the graphs from the ajax success function with the JSON plugged in

Answer (score 0):

You can do as [Graham T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/591626/graham-t) said, which should be done but suppose if it is necessary to interact with a different file then what you can do is you can make a function. Suppose:

```
function calculate_sum(a, b){
  $('#sum').html(a + b)
}
```

Now in the view you have this div:

```
<div id='sum'>
</div>
```

Now you send a AJAX request and suppose the action name is `evaluate_sum` so you will make a file name `evaluate_sum.js.erb` and in the controller you are assigning `a` and `b` in `@first_no` and `@second_no` so in the file `evaluate_sum.js.erb`:

```
calculate_sum(<%= @first_no %>, <%= @second_no %>)
```

So this `function calculate_sum(a, b)` can be declared in any `js` file included in the page. This is a very simple example and can be implemented in many different ways like you can create a partial for this etc. It depends on your case and on you.

Hope this helps.